# Configuring JsonOutputFormatter using AddMvcCore

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to setup a slimline ASP.NET Core pipeline and am using `AddMvcCore` instead of `AddMvc`. I've copied this mostly from [AddMvc](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/9f3dfd98194d94362586bd5a8c1dccec9df38a48/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc/MvcServiceCollectionExtensions.cs), omitting the Razor related items:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) =>
    services
        .AddMvcCore(
            options => 
            {
                // JsonOutputFormatter not found in OutputFormatters!
                var jsonOutputFormatter = 
                    options.OutputFormatters.OfType<JsonOutputFormatter>.First();
                jsonOutputFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add("application/ld+json");
            })
        .AddApiExplorer()
        .AddAuthorization()
        .AddFormatterMappings()
        .AddRazorViewEngine()
        .AddRazorPages()
        .AddCacheTagHelper()
        .AddDataAnnotations()
        .AddJsonFormatters()
        .AddCors();
```

I want to add a MIME type to the `JsonOutputFormatter` but it can't be found in the `OutputFormatters` collection. That said, the app can still output JSON, so I think the `JsonOutputFormatter` is being added at a later time. How can I get hold of the JsonOutputFormatter?

Comment: If you add the JsonOutputFormatter to the output formatters with your MIME type addition, does it have the affect that you're after, or is it overridden?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `AddMvcOptions` at the end (position is important) to access the JSON formatters after they have been added:

```
services
    .AddMvcCore()
    .AddJsonFormatters()
    .AddMvcOptions(options => { // do your work here });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) =>
services
    .AddMvcCore(
        options => 
        {
            var jsonOutputFormatter = options.OutputFormatters.FirstOrDefault(p => p.GetType() == typeof(JsonOutputFormatter)) as JsonOutputFormatter;

            // Then add
            jsonOutputFormatter?.SupportedMediaTypes.Add("application/ld+json");
        })
    .AddApiExplorer()
    .AddAuthorization()
    .AddFormatterMappings()
    .AddRazorViewEngine()
    .AddRazorPages()
    .AddCacheTagHelper()
    .AddDataAnnotations()
    .AddJsonFormatters()
    .AddCors();
```